# Resolving Pointers

Tags: pointers, go

I'm a bit new to Go (Golang) and am getting a bit confused by pointers. In particular, I can't seem to figure out how to resolve or dereference a pointer.

The following is an example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type someStruct struct {
    propertyOne int
    propertyTwo map[string]interface{}
}

func NewSomeStruct() *someStruct {
    return &someStruct{
        propertyOne: 41,
    }
}

func aFunc(aStruct *someStruct) {
    aStruct.propertyOne = 987
}

func bFunc(aStructAsValue someStruct) {
    // I want to make sure that I do not change the struct passed into this function.
    aStructAsValue.propertyOne = 654
}

func main() {
    structInstance := NewSomeStruct()
    fmt.Println("My Struct:", structInstance)

    structInstance.propertyOne = 123 // I will NOT be able to do this if the struct was in another package.
    fmt.Println("Changed Struct:", structInstance)

    fmt.Println("Before aFunc:", structInstance)
    aFunc(structInstance)
    fmt.Println("After aFunc:", structInstance)

    // How can I resolve/dereference "structInstance" (type *someStruct) into
    // something of (type someStruct) so that I can pass it into bFunc?

    // &structInstance produces (type **someStruct)

    // Perhaps I'm using type assertion incorrectly?
    //bFunc(structInstance.(someStruct))
}
```

### Code on "Go Playground"

http://play.golang.org/p/FlTh7_cuUb

**In the example above, is it possible to call "bFunc" with "structInstance"?**

This could potentially be even more of an issue if the "someStruct" struct is in another package and since it's unexported, the only way to get an instance of it will be through some "New" function (which, let's say will all return pointers).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing 2 issues here, this has nothing to do with pointers, it has to do with exported variables.

```
type someStruct struct {
    propertyOne int
    propertyTwo map[string]interface{}
}
```

`someStruct`, `propertyOne` and `propertyTwo` aren't exported (they don't start with a capital letter), so even if you use `NewSomeStruct` from another package, you wouldn't be able to access the fields.

And about `bFunc`, you dereference a pointer by appending `*` before the variable name, for [example](http://play.golang.org/p/nsC1xLL7fn):

```
bFunc(*structInstance)
```

I highly recommend going through [Effective Go](http://tip.golang.org/doc/effective_go.html), specially the [Pointers vs. Values](http://tip.golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values) section.

Comment: I understand that names that do not begin with a capital letter are not exported beyond its containing package. In fact, that was the main motivation behind this question -- I didn't want the user directly modifying the underlying struct of some object so I pass back the pointer to an unexported struct (but couldn't figure out how to use the pointer for some method that takes a value [not pointer] of that struct).

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out the section on "Effective Go" but while the page showed how to do "Value -> Pointer", I wasn't able to find out how to do the "Pointer -> Value" conversion addressed in this question.

Comment: Upon further experimentation, I came up with another question -- methods with pointer receivers still seem callable by values (assuming that value is assigned to some variable). Is there anyway to prevent that while still being able to store the instance of some struct in a variable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277309/method-defined-on-pointer-still-callable-with-value